# Monitoring Significant Location Changes, App closed GPS signal (Arrow)

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, location

First of all I hope don't repeat any topic, I have spent a lot of time reading on internet about this before ask.

I'm developing an app for iOS => 5 and I need get the user location, but I don't need always a great accurate position, so when the app goes to background I change the normal location mode to Significant Location Changes and when the app come to foreground I stop the significant location change mode and get back the normal location mode, that's all goes fine,

my problem is when the app goes to background mode or even the user KILL the app the GPS signal (the purple arrow) still appear ALWAYS, even after restart the device, the only way to make disappear it is un-installing the or disabling the significant location changes when the app goes to background, but I need this mode working when the user goes to background mode, maybe not when the app is killed.

I don't know how to stop the service when the user kill the app... because event "applicationWillTerminate" is not called if you have multitask ON.

My main reason because I don't want the purple arrow appear always, even the app is killed is because I don't want the user think the app is drying the battery... so the user won't want the app installed.

First question: Is normal that the purple arrow appear always, even the app is killed if the Significant location change is enabled for the app?

Second question: Is any way to change this, to stop the service at least when the app is killed to hide the purple arrow?

Thank you all.
Sorry for my english if something is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After few days researching to be sure about this service, seems like there is NO way to use significant locations change in the background without the arrow in the top bar. I have been testing with different apps and reading through internet and nothing to solve this.

The only ""way to solve"" this is disable multitask mode in the app and disable the significant locations change in the event "applicationWillTerminate" but don't make sense... I'm losing the background location always not only when the app is killed... so is not useful.

It's bad... is a really good service to get locations saving battery but as user and developer I don't want an app that make appear this icon ALWAYS even after the app is killed, as developer I don't want that people uninstall the app for this reason and as normal user I don't know what mean this icon if is normal GPS or Significant locations change and what mean this... if my battery is being drain or not.

The other option to get locations in background task but has a big impact over the battery....

I hope apple fix this in future versions... adding at least a new arrow or showing only when a new location arrive instad of always or allowing to stooped when the app is killed.

All this has been researched over iOS - 6.1

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the significant location change service, the OS keeps your app running. If the app is in the background and is killed, the OS restarts it, so the purple arrow will always show. When a new location is detected, the app is restarted. From the docs:

> If you leave this service running and your app is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service automatically wakes up your app when new location data arrives. At wake-up time, your app is put into the background and given a small amount of time to process the location data.  ... To stop the significant change location service, call the `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the doc say "the service automatically wakes up your app when new location data arrives", but I'm not getting any location update just close the app, it should be disappear until next location update when the app will be wake up?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, interesting.  I've just seen that problem with another app - seeing the arrow still active made me want to disable location updates for that app so the problem is real.  Best thing I can think of is to have some kind of timer to disable the location monitoring after a certain amount of time if that is appropriate for your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, maybe I'm wrong but if the app is killed I can not make any background task or timer to disable it after a few time. Is that's right?

Comment: You'll get an applicationWillTerminate if the OS wants to kill your app, but I don't think you get anything if the user kills it.  So it doesn't sound like a total fix for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but yes... it's not total fixing the problem... the user still will think in disabled completely the location or remove the app if the kill the app and still appear the icon...